# UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity with IdentityType.Guid returns no results

Tags: c#, active-directory, account-management

I'm searching users on Active Directory using `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement`.

Here' a simple example

```
using System;
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;

public static class DomainHelpers
{
    public string GetDistinguishedName(string domain, string guid)
    {
        var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, domain);
        var userPrincipal = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.Guid, guid);

        return userPrincipal.DistinguishedName;
    }
}
```

The userPrincipal is always null. If I change IdentityType.Guid to IdentityType.SamAccountName and search for the samaccountname, it works just fine. If I take the guid property of that userPrincipal object that I got when searching for the samAccountName, I once again get no response.

Any ideas what I need to do to get results using the guid? I'm under the distinct impression that a couple years back when I wrote this code, it used to work just fine. But back then I had Windows 2008 R2 as DCs, now I have Windows 2016.

If I access the `DirectoryEntry` directly, so using

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry($"LDAP://{DomainName}/<GUID={objectGuid}>"))
```

Things work as expected. So it's a problem inherent with `UserPrincipal.FindIdentity'. I also tried supplying the NativeGuid to FindByIdentity, but it doesn't change things a bit.

Comment: Not really.. I came from that other thread, it provides no answer except for the workaround of going through the DirectoryEntry. But that's not what I need. The rest of my code works with the UserPrincipal Object and there's times where I need to search by SamAccountName/UPN and times I need to search by ObjectGuid.

Comment: @user1547915 Just a thought which I came across when trying to help find a solution, you aren't using the `SID` value in place of the `Guid` are you? Some people mistakenly used the `SID` value

Comment: Nope, it's most definitely the guid. The value called objectGuid when you do navtive LDAP. Or UserPrincipal.Guid.Value when going through the UserPrincipal object. You can detect that by looking at the string representation: The Guid is something like this: 3f832663-3492-46b1-bac8-e286dab142d8, and SID looks like this: S-1-5-21-2893744555-524998179-1716630349-1581. Quite a difference.

Comment: @user1547915 Yeah, was just kind of spit-balling ideas.. I am looking for any other things you can try. Can you post what you are passing as the string representation of the guid you are searching for?

Comment: the string I'm sending is the Guid I posted before: "3f832663-3492-46b1-bac8-e286dab142d8". Converted to native guid format, it would be "6326833f9234b146bac8e286dab142d8". Both do not work

Comment: any chance there is some whitespace in the actual value? Also, what happens if you search with the guid, but use the overloaded `FindByIdentity` ommitting the `Identity.Type` enum?

Comment: Nope, the above code is a repro.. I'm actually sending the fully parsed object down to my real method, so the value being send would be new Guid("3f832663-3492-46b1-bac8-e286dab142d8").ToString() which I verified comes back as the exact string I want.

Comment: Are the two accounts (your service account and your customer's personal admin account) on different domains?

Comment: I poked through the [source code for the .NET Core implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement/src/System/DirectoryServices/AccountManagement/AD/ADStoreCtx_Query.cs#L472). `FindByIdentity` builds an LDAP query to search by `objectGuid` instead of using the direct bind method (`LDAP://<GUID=>`). The method described here (the GUID byte array has to be encoded into the LDAP query): https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/ivfranji/ad-ldap-search-octetstring-2/

Comment: Some updates: I wrote a repro tool for my customer, and of course with that tool, the lookup works just fine. Then we discovered that if I turn off all security, so setting ContextOptions to ConextOptions.SimpleBind and supplying the options to the PrincipalContext constructor, the lookup once again does work. So it seems to be a security thing of some sorts.